# Is there a global action for when a plugin is uninstalled?

Tags: plugins, actions

I need to do something anytime any plugin is uninstalled. There's a hook for when MY plugin is uninstalled but I don't see an uninstall equivalent of `deactivated_plugin`.  Does uninstalling a plugin fire the deactivation action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `deactivated_plugin` won't fire during a plugin's uninstallation process. But there are indeed two hooks that fire when a plugin is uninstalled:

- [`pre_uninstall_plugin`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_uninstall_plugin/), which is called right before a plugin is uninstalled. It acts globally, targeting any plugin.
- [`uninstall_{$file}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/uninstall_file/), which fires after a specific plugin is uninstalled. Its scope it's limited to a unique plugin with basename `{$file}`. If you want to access the basenames of the whole plugins list, you can check the keys in the array that [`get_plugins()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugins/) returns.